# Chromium: The Hunt

Tags: windows, google-chrome, download, chromium

Where do I download Chromium? It seems unnecessarily confusing. Why isint there a big download button on the Chromium website?

**Chromium Download Link: http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium**

Comment: Which OS are you using? Some of the *nixes are offering it in their repos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is where you can get all the Chromium binaries as they are released:

http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/

Comment: Anyone knows if these builds have an auto update feature (and if so, to which version they update)? Would be cool if they autoupdate to something stable.

Comment: Directory seems to be empty as of 23-02-2012. There's an 'snapshot-old' above, but the newest builds there are dated 2011.

Answer (score 4):

```
Where do I download Chromium?
```

I use [softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Internet/Browsers/Portable-Google-Chrome-Chromium.shtml) to search for Chromium. They always have the newest builds compiled and ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a website put up by "Hexxeh" offering [nightly builds of Chromium Vanilla](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/vanilla.php).

I tried out a VBox image a couple of weeks ago, and it was pretty slow. Kind of to be expected, since there are no drivers built-in for VBox. So you should probably follow Hexxeh's advice and try the usb image.

Comment: My bad, looks like you want the browser, not the OS. :-) However, I'll leave the answer for anybody that finds the post that might be interested.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I download Chromium?

<s>You sort of can't. There aren't</s> @Acorn's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/309590/chromium-the-hunt/309593#309593) points to >[binary builds of Chromium](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/)> - you can also [grab the sources](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/) & [compile them](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos).

Comment: This is not true, check the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [continuous build](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html) which may be little more "stale" (as stated [here](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code#TOC-Continuous-build)) because it must pass both unit tests and layouts tests on particular platform.